# hog+svm classification takes too mcuh time

Tags: python, parallel-processing

i  have  directory called Animal- which consist of  two subdirectory(cats and dogs), create  a full path for each file  does not take too much time and it returns quickly, here is sample code :

```
import  cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.feature import hog
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import os
mypca =PCA(n_components=10)
parent ="Animal"
file_list =[]
features =[]
labels =[]
subdirectory =os.listdir(parent)
for  animal in subdirectory:
    full_directory =os.path.join(parent,animal)
    for  file in os.listdir(full_directory):
        file_path =os.path.join(full_directory,file)
        file_list.append(file_path)
print(file_list)
```

i am saving  full path for each file in order to avoid nested loop, then i should iterate  through list and  read each image one-by-one and  apply hog  feature  extraction algorithm, here is  this code :

```
for file in file_list:
    image =cv2.imread(file)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (128 * 4, 64 * 4))
    fd, hog_image = hog(image, orientations=9, pixels_per_cell=(8, 8),
                            cells_per_block=(4, 4), visualize=True, multichannel=True)
    features.append(fd)
    if file.find("cats") !=-1:
        labels.append(0)
    else:
        labels.append(1)
labels =np.array(labels)
features =np.array(features)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test =train_test_split(features,labels,test_size=0.2,random_state=1)
X_train =mypca.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test =mypca.transform(X_test)
mymodel =SVC()
mymodel.fit(X_train,y_train)
print(mymodel.score(X_test,y_test))
print(features.shape)
```

but this code takes too much time(even my computer  HP Omen has  6  cpu qore), could you please advice   me how to accelerate execution time? originally in directory there  was  4000 image in each category and i have deleted more then 2000, but still  waiting for long time untill it finished  operation, i have tried  as well to apply PCA in order to  reduce dimensionality.what would be your recomendation?

Comment: Can you provide a benchmark of how much time extracting the hog features takes vs training the machine learning model? (you can use `time.perf_counter`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `sklearn.svm.SVC` method that is inappropriate for large datasets, as it becomes too inefficient as it scales quadratically or more, from the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html):

> The implementation is based on libsvm. The fit time scales at least
> quadratically with the number of samples and may be impractical beyond
> tens of thousands of samples. For large datasets consider using
> LinearSVC or SGDClassifier instead, possibly after a Nystroem
> transformer or other Kernel Approximation.

Comment: do you think that it  is main reason of  such long time?

Comment: @neuralscience I can only think that it is because I cannot benchmark your code. You have the dataset so you can run the code with this change and tell me if the performance improves enough or not

Comment: so use LinearSVC right?

Comment: @neuralscience LinearSVC or SGDClassifier

Comment: time is almost same,if i run  hog algorithm for one image, it works fine, intotal there is 3000 image maybe because of this  it  takes so much time

Comment: Another way to increase performance is `pixels_per_cell = (16, 16)` or `pixels_per_cell = (32, 32)` keep in mind that this might decrease accuracy

Comment: yes , but because  original image  size is not big, (16,16) or (32,32)  may not lead good  result

Comment: @neuralscience I understand but performance and accuracy are always at a tradeoff between each other. You can try (16, 16) and see if the accuracy drops and how much

Comment: especially  if you are  using  not enough strong computer,  if we consider computer  that run chatGPT(as i know  it has ram of 400 GB) definitely performance and accuracy may not   fight against each other, but computer having ram just 16 GB or even 32  of course can be serious reason for some cases

Comment: Of course another way to increase performance is `image = cv2.resize(image, (128 * 4, 64 * 4))` reducing the size of the image, but this might also reduce performance

Comment: that  why we should use computer ,with  has  60 core  and RAM having  1000 GB  and  hard drive  of SSD with rocket speed(but definitely havimg such computer means borrowing  hume amount of money from bank  :D :D )

Comment: @neuralscience yeah, a supercomputer would be so good for data science... did you try my suggestions? I am very curious how performance and accuracy would change

Comment: i  applied  previous suggestions, it  took a bit less time. thanks for recomendation.

Comment: @neuralscience can you share a few metrics (time in seconds, accuracy)? I am curious

Comment: let us  do   it  in   a few days ok? because i   searching and doing something else(related to the web scrapping) , please remind me  it in two days and i will run again and share information ok?

Comment: @neuralscience no problem, good luck for your project